# Using Filter on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: filter, google-sheets

I want to apply a filter to my Google spreadsheet.

Column J of my `AllCurrent` sheet has some rows with value `2016` so why isn't this working?
I threw in my  `=IF(MONTH(TODAY()) > 4,YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY()))` part in a cell and it evaluated to 2016.

Here's the filter: `=filter(AllCurrent!A2:Z,AllCurrent!J2:J = IF(MONTH(TODAY()) > 4,YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY())))`

Comment: No matches are found in FILTER evaluation

Comment: This works to count rows with value 2016 in Column J...=COUNTIF(AllCurrent!J2:J , IF(MONTH(TODAY()) > 4,YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY())))

Comment: pnuts, just saw your second question. Answer is... 2016

Comment: AllCurrent! is populated by data from another spreadsheet by =query(importrange(... but I doubt that has anything to do with it.

Comment: It appears to be a text vs number thing. This works: =filter(AllCurrent!A2:Z,AllCurrent!J2:J = "2016") This doesn't: =filter(AllCurrent!A2:Z,AllCurrent!J2:J = 2016) So how do I make IF(MONTH(TODAY()) > 4,YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY())) return a text value?

Comment: Found it: to_text() around the if() That Works. I thought the conversion was made automatically.

Comment: If I create a filter view on AllCurrent with a custom formula for Column J of =TO_TEXT(IF(MONTH(TODAY()) > 4,YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY()))) that returns no rows. I'm finding that working with Google Spreadsheets is very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=FILTER(AllCurrent!A2:Z,ARRAYFORMULA(VALUE(AllCurrent!J2:J) = IF(MONTH(TODAY()) > 4,YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY()))))`

Comment: Yes, that works as well as this... `=filter(AllCurrent!A2:Z,AllCurrent!J2:J = TO_TEXT(IF(MONTH(TODAY()) > 4,YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY()))))`